# How we can protect images in our web application?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am working on a web application using PHP and application consist lots of images.We are also using same image when creating a PDF in our application and users can also download/save from PDF. I am worried that these can easily be taken by unscrupulous individuals. Is there any way to protect these images ? Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Generally the best accepted practice is to let people download low resolution images (72 dpi or less) that are really only good for printing on small media with watermarks to deter reusage. And charge for full res/no watermark images.

Comment: A good solution would be to display your images using flash and overlay them with a watermark. Using flash makes it much harder for users to rip your images. A good addition to this would be hashing the filenames with a date. Even though the filenames are passed on the background, people could Always find out the urls. This will be prevented by hashing them.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely impossible to protect the images that user see.
If you aren't convinced, a simple evidence: you can simply take a screenshot. And voila! Here are your images. Even if you came up with the wittiest solution ever invented.

The only possible ways of securing your images are:

- very ugly - adding a watermark
- reducing the image size - assuming it's only worthy in hi-quality

Also, keep in mind that even if you came up with cool technology, eventually cooler guy would come down and crack your security. So my advice is, don't try wasting your time on this idea. Instead, try planning better access-to-these-images work model and/or limit the number of valuable images shown to just few.

Comment: Well said, if a user is able to see it, they are able to rip it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has access to view the image, they can screen print it. You cannot protect it unless it is behind a login area for instance. You could add a watermark to help deter this but they can still take the image and crop the watermark off.